# как во время парсинга сайта с новостями перейти по самой статье и прочитать ее(python)

Tags: python, парсер

есть код парсера по сайту с новостями, он собирает и выводит заголовки статей, а как пропарсить сами эти статьи, чтобы прочитать полностю?

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

spis = []
spis2 = []
sesssion = requests.Session()

new = requests.get('https://www.vesti.ru/news')
html = bs(new.content, 'html.parser')
count = 0

for i in html.select('.b-item__info'):
    title2 = i.select('.b-item__title > a')
    spis.append(str(title2))
for j in spis:
    string = list(j)
    d = string[32:-5]
    spis2.append(''.join(d))
for i in spis2:
    print(i)```
````

Comment: Там должен быть тег со ссылкой на статью, вытаскиваете её и реквестом переходите

Comment: @Nobody хорошо, а помогите пожалуйста правильно к этому тегу обратиться, я впервые работаю с парсером

Comment: В хроме на сайт зайдите и нажмите F12, посмотрите код страницы там, как она в принципе устроена. Я с телефона не смогу помочь

Comment: @Nobody да, я так и делал, я имею в виду код

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим сайт вестей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Список всех новостей это div с классом news-wrapper_. Каждая новость имеет класс b-item__inner а информация о ссылке на статью и ее названии хранится в теге а. Соответсвенно такой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urljoin

domain = 'https://www.vesti.ru/news'
r = requests.get(domain)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
news_area = soup.find("div", {"class":"news-wrapper_"})
news = news_area.find_all("div", {"class":"b-item__inne"})
for new news:
   heading = new.find("h3", {"class":"b-item__title"})
   name = heading.find("a").get_text()
   #link = domain + heading.find("a").get("href") #Т к ссылка указана без домена 
   link = urljoin(domain, heading.find("a").get("href"))
   #Второй способ генерации ссылок предпочтительнее.
   news_text = requests.get(link).content
   print(name, link, news_text)
```

И еще скажу вам на будущее что в соответствии со стандартом PEP - 8  вы должна давать названия переменным которые отражают содержание, spis j итп - далеко не лучший выбор.

Comment: Для создания абсолютных ссылок лучше используйте `urljoin`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f2db9a9ff9d9bb61360c9b32aa2574681f968809/html_parsing/vesti_ru__news.py#L19

Comment: Спасибо, я добавил в код.

Comment: Он мне ничего не выводит, просто код выполняется за 1.5 секунды и все

Comment: @BlueScreen, вместо указания домена руками, лучше взять его из `requests.Response`, т.е. `link = urljoin(new.url, heading.find("a").get("href"))` :)

Comment: @Руслан попробуйте написать после строки new = requests.get(domain) print(new) Возможно будет Response<403> что означает что сервер не дал ответ по "личным причинам"

Comment: @BlueScreen так и случилось, толькл response 200,  но все таки, в конце программы должна была выводиться информация, почему она не выводится, а просто игнорируется?

Comment: @Руслан Не выводится ничиего или выводится пустая строка?